# What software should i use to create a ERP SYSTEM?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, asp.net, mongodb

i would like you help me with this question. if you have to make a software  ERP , with modules like Human Resource, Inventory, Sales & Marketing, Purches, Finance & Accounting, Customer Relationship Management(CRM),Engineering/Production, etc. what database, backend and front end would  you choose? Thanks  you in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment, so I will have to post this as an answer …

How many years do you have available for the project? Because it ***will** take years (at a rough guess, man-decades).

- Spend a good few months coming up with requirements; then have someone review them (do you have a customer or end user?) .
- Then spend longer on an architecture. Review.
- Then do some detailed design. Have it reviewed.
- After 6 to 12 man months, you ***might*** be in a position to write your first line of code. Have your code reviewed.
- For a project this big, set up Continuous integration, probably using Jenkins, make sure that you have ***lots*** of unit tests, plus end to end tests.
- Make sure that they are automated and that your CI runs them every night – and with every commit to version control (did forget to remind you to use version control?).
- And so on, and so on, and so on.

***OR***, sit back and ask yourself if you really want to reinvent this particular wheel, or whether you just want to use some free software and use your time more profitably. This is not really a one person project, and even with a bunch of you, you are unlikely to do anything new (no offence intended; it’s just that there are already so many).